# Is it possible to follow a developer on Gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Just moved to Gitlab and found some interesting people there.

It'd be great to be able to follow them like in Github. I can't really find an answer on search engines. And there is no button I can see on Gitlab.

Is this possible? Or I should make a suggestion to Gitlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option to follow people on `Gitlab` is currently unavailable, But the proposal is already made an year ago and was reported in [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30868) issue. Hope we get this near soon.

Answer (score 0):

It was supported before, but [GitLab 15.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#follow-or-unfollow-someone-from-the-user-popup) (May 2022) further simplifies the process:

> ### Follow or unfollow someone from the user popup
>
> Before this release, you could only follow or unfollow a GitLab user from their user profile. It was difficult to know if you were following a specific user unless you viewed the user’s profile.
>
> In this release, thanks to [Kev](https://gitlab.com/KevSlashNull)’s contribution, you can quickly follow and unfollow users through the user popup, no matter where you are in your GitLab workflow: in notes, issues, and more.
> This reduces the extra step of going to the user’s profile, and makes it easier to follow and unfollow other GitLab users.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_0/follow.png -- Follow or unfollow someone from the user popup]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#user-activity) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/353362).